# how computer store a number a little bigger than machine epsilon?

Tags: matlab

e.g I have stored a float number bigger than epsilon and less than 2epsilon, so how does the coumputer store such a number rather than change it into epsilon because of float number rules.

Comment: Epsilon is *relative*. You cannot make a number between 1 and 1+eps. But you can make many numbers between 0.001 and 0.001+eps.

Comment: You may find [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/686454/2586922) useful

Answer (score 0):

eps is defined as the smallest positive number that when added to 1.0 gives a number different than 1.0

If you want the smallest number near some other number x, use `eps(x)`

To see the details of how these numbers are stored, look into the [IEEE specs for floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).